# Manually release ComPtr

Tags: c++, com

I'm using ComPtr (Microsoft::WRL) to manage some DirectX11 resources.
How can I manually release it?

The "ReleaseAndGetAddressOf" method if I understand correctly, only frees the pointer and not the resource itself (which is returned), and I'm not sure about the "Reset" method.

The only alternatives I could think of are manually calling the pointer destructor, or after obtaining the raw pointer from "ReleaseAndGetAddressOf" calling "Release" on that, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Your description of ReleaseAndGetAddressOf() is incorrect. It does release the resource, and returns the address of the wrapped pointer where you could store another pointer value. "Calling Release on that" should be written "Calling Release on a now-dangling pointer, to crash my program".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The source code for WRL is provided, have a look at include/winrt/wrl/client.h.  The embedded COM pointer (ptr_ member) is released by the InternalRelease() function.  Making any of the following a way to release the pointer suitable candidates:

- the destructor.  The reason to use ComPtr<>
- assigning nullptr
- using ReleaseAndGetAddressOf(), the long way around
- calling Reset()

So assigning nullptr or calling Reset() are a good fit, take your pick.  Or don't use it at all if you just want to manage the interface pointer yourself, it certainly isn't required to use ComPtr.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I actually gain benefit from using a smart pointer, but in some case I have to unload the internal resource while maintaining the wrapper class.

Answer (score 4):

You can assign a null pointer.

Comment: Thank you, as easy as I could have hoped for!